# is it valid to async send data before completion handler of the previous one was invoked?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, asyncsocket

I'm sending data asynchronously to TCP socket. Is it valid to send the next data piece before the previous one was reported as sent by completion handler?

As I know it's not allowed when sending is done from different threads. In my case all sending are done from the same thread.

Different modules of my client send data to the same socket. E.g. module1 sent some data and will continue when corresponding completion handler is invoked. Before this `io_service` invoked `deadline_timer` handler of module2 which leads to another `async_write` call. Should I expect any problems here?

Comment: TCP sockets do not send packets, they send streams of data. I clarified your question's title.

Comment: tnx. In general, I cannot agree, TCP sockets still send packets as any other sockets. TCP interface is designed to represent this as a  stream, but this is just an abstraction to give more freedom for TCP stack algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it valid to send the next data piece before the previous one was
>   reported as sent by completion handler?

No it is not valid to interleave write operations. This is **very clear** in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
>   stream's `async_write_some` function, and is known as a composed
>   operation. **The program must ensure that the stream performs no other
>   write operations** (such as `async_write`, the stream's `async_write_some`
>   function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) **until
>   this operation completes**.

emphasis added by me.

> As I know it's not allowed when sending is done from different
>   threads. In my case all sending are done from the same thread.

Your problem has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: how about async_send?  It's not mentioned in the documentation.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send/overload1.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that as long as the underlying memory (buffer) is not modified until the write handler is called. Calling `async_write` means you hand over the buffer ownership to Asio. When the write handler is called, the buffer ownership is given back to you.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, how do you ensure the writes are not interleaved?

Comment: @SamMiller: they are if done from multiple threads. I don't expect this happens when writes and `io_service::run()` are done in single thread since tasks are put into queue and executed in FIFO order (at least I think so).